# Get all attributes in Attribute Editor under AD User properties

Tags: c#, powershell

I need to get all attributes listed in Attribute Editor ([Attribute Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHPHV.png)) when view properties of an AD user (~300 attributes) using C# or Power Shell.

I tried to query the schema user but not get enough attributes.

```bsh
Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemaNamingContext -Filter {name -like "User"} -Properties MayContain,SystemMayContain |
Select-Object @{n="Attributes";e={$_.maycontain + $_.systemmaycontain}} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Attributes |
Sort-Object
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following "recursive" function should work. It takes into account the inheritance of attributes from parent classes.

```
function Get-AllAttributes {
    Param($class)

    $temp = get-adobject -searchbase (get-adrootdse).schemanamingcontext -filter "ldapdisplayname -eq '$class'" -Properties SystemMayContain,subClassOf,ldapdisplayname,MayContain
    $temp.systemMayContain
    $temp.MayContain
    while($temp.subClassOf -and $temp.ldapdisplayname -ne $temp.subClassOf) {
        $temp = get-adobject -searchbase (get-adrootdse).schemanamingcontext -filter "ldapdisplayname -eq '$($temp.subClassOf)'" -Properties SystemMayContain,subClassOf,ldapdisplayname,MayContain
        $temp.systemMayContain
        $temp.MayContain
    }
}

Get-AllAttributes 'user'
```

Comment: It shows almost attributes but missing some attributes such as "accountNameHistory", "altSecurityIdentities". Could you please help to check?

Comment: I honestly don’t think there is a solution that works for everybody. Neither of these solutions work if you have Exchange, for example.

Comment: I combine results from the 2 classes below. Thank you!
```Get-AllAttributes 'user' + Get-AllAttributes 'securityPrincipal' | sort -unique```

Answer (score 0):

While probing the schema gets you a lot of attributes, there are also attributes (systemFlags) that are not defined in the schema, but are calculated when asked for.

The below function should get all of these:

```
function Get-AllADUserAttributes {
    # First, get all AD user attributes defined in the Active Directory schema
    $searchBase    = (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemaNamingContext
    $schemaAttribs = Get-ADObject -SearchBase $searchBase -Filter {name -like "User"} -Properties MayContain,SystemMayContain |
                     Select-Object @{Name = 'Attributes'; Expression = {$_.maycontain + $_.systemmaycontain}} |
                     Select-Object -ExpandProperty Attributes

    # Next, get all created user attributes. These are not defined in the schema, but calculated when asked for
    $flagsAttribs = Get-ADObject -SearchBase $searchBase -ldapfilter '(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=4)' -Properties systemFlags |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

    return ($schemaAttribs + $flagsAttribs) | Sort-Object
}
```

Comment: I run the script but getting below error: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:11 char:12
+     return ($schemaAttribs + $flagsAttribs) | Sort-Object Attributes
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @PhucNguyen Sorry, my bad. I forgot to do `-ExpandProperty` in the previous code. Should be fixed now.